# HtmlPurifier: Remove Ambiguous WhiteSpace?

Tags: formatting, whitespace, htmlpurifier, removing-whitespace

Is it possible to remove ambiguous whitespace from a string containing html with HTMLPurifier?  I wasn't able to find anything relevant in the documentation.  I'm also open to other methods if they exist.

Example Input:

```
    Test Line1
<p>
    Test Line2</p>
<p>
    Line 3</p>
```

Optimal Output:

```
Test Line1<p>Test Line2</p><p>Line 3</p>
```

Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can regular expression help?

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $text)
```

Comment: My experience with regex is limited; what is this classifying as ambiguous text? Thanks!

Comment: \s = <any whitespace symbol>
+ = 1..n time(s)

Comment: span style becomes spanstyle :-)